# Call to undefined method whereBetween

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 table with many to many relationship.
Customer Model >>

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Mmtimes\MmtimesLib\Models\Product','customer_product','customer_id','product_id')->withPivot('first_copy','last_copy','to_date');
}
```

Product Model >>

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Mmtimes\MmtimesLib\Models\Customer', 'customer_product', 'product_id', 'customer_id');
}
```

I pull data according to "to_date" column >>

```
public function getCustomerByDate()
{
    $todate = date('Y-m-d');
    $date = strtotime($todate);
    $date = strtotime("+7 day",$date);
    $date = date('Y-m-d',$date);

    $customers = $this->model->products()->whereBetween('to_date',[$todate,$date])->get();
    var_dump($customers);
    die();
}
```

I got the error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereBetween()

Please show me the right way ... Thanks and respect to all .

Answer (score 0):

You can't use whereBetween directly eloquent way. Its a query builder method. In case of you want to use it with eloquent it should be called within a [Query Scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes).

Comment: I have no idea how to pull out the [customer] data . Can u show me the way or link me some tutorials . Thanks